# How to vertically center the last item in a list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I had some code like this:

```css
.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">a</div>
<div class="item">b</div>
<div class="item">c</div>
<div class="item">d</div>
<div class="item">e</div>
```

This list can be anywhere from 1 to 50 elements long. My desire is to have the last item in the list vertically centered in its container.

That is, if the list is only one element long, then that one element is vertically centered alone.

However, if there are 5 elements (as is the case in this example), then when you scroll down to the end of the container, that last element is vertically centered in the user's viewport.

For example, if the user's viewport is 400 pixels wide and 600 pixels high, then when they reach the bottom of the page then the last item would have a margin-bottom of 150px (because it's 300 pixels tall and the viewport is 600 pixels high, so it needs to be 150px from the bottom to be centered)

Is this possible?

Comment: All of the divs already appear to be centered.  There is one div per line.  You would need to change the code to have "a b" be one line, "c d" another, and "e" to be the last, and then to center ONLY "e" -- if I am understanding what you're asking for?

Comment: Not horizontally centered, vertically centered. The position of divs a through d is fine, I would just like the last div to have enough margin bottom for it to be positioned in the center of your screen when you're fully scrolled down the page.

Comment: Hi, Ryan, thanks for getting back to me, after deleting my answer and reworking it, hopefully I have a good working answer now.

Comment: @RyanPeschel did my answer solve your query or were you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set margin bottom of the last child to be half the view height minus half the item height, then if the last child is the first child do the same for margin top, that should do the trick.

```css
.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: calc(50vh - 150px)
}

.item:first-child:last-child {
  margin-top: calc(50vh - 150px)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">d</div>
    <div class="item">e</div>
</div>
```

```css
.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: calc(50vh - 150px)
}

.item:first-child:last-child {
  margin-top: calc(50vh - 150px)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is getting there, but does `vh` refer to the screen height and not the container height? Also, this requires knowing the height of each div, correct? My divs can have a dynamic height.

Comment: so you need bottom margin to always be half the height of the container minus half the height of the last element but both are not fixed, and something similar for top margin, then this approach won't work unless if you get their size with javascript

Comment: Well, this might be good enough in any case. It's not ideal but most of the divs are _around_ the same height so maybe it won't be too noticeable..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `last-of-type` to select the last element of a type, and then on that type, set `margin-bottom:50vh` (50% of the "view-port height").

[**Full Working Demo**](https://jsbin.com/yomubepusi/1/edit?html,css,output).  Oddly, the code snippet below doesn't seem to produce the same result as several other places I've demo'd.

*It is vertically centered, regardless of view-port.*

Full Viewport Demo: [image]

Short Viewport Demo: [image]

Vertically-centered in both cases.

All the `div`'s are already horizontally-centered, this will vertically center the last div.  [**Official Documentation for `last-of-type`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)...

> The :last-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents the last element of its type among a group of sibling elements.

This approach is also dependent on `vh`, or view-port widths.  To quote the [**Official Documentation for `vh`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)...

> vw: Equal to 1% of the height of the viewport's initial containing block.

```css
    .item {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      background-color: #f3f3f3;
      margin: 15px auto;
    }

    div:last-of-type {
        margin-bottom:50vh;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">d</div>
    <div class="item">e</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```css
.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  margin: 15px auto;
  display: flex;
}

.item:nth-last-child(1) {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="item">a</div>
<div class="item">b</div>
<div class="item">c</div>
<div class="item">d</div>
<div class="item">e</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd try using the CSS `:nth-last-child()` pseudo-class that matches elements based on their position among a group of siblings, counting from the end.

You can check it out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child

```css
.item {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      background-color: #f3f3f3;
      margin: 15px auto;
    }

.item:nth-last-child(1) {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
<div class="item">a</div>
<div class="item">b</div>
<div class="item">c</div>
<div class="item">d</div>
<div class="item">e</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the `last-child` selector and it probably will be used here, but I don't see how to use it to affect this desired change.

Comment: @RyanPeschel I've updated my answer with an example. You should have all of your div's inside a "group". In the example I posted they're inside a <ul>